# Insert value of variable into a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to insert the value of a variable into a file.

I have tried redirection, but it isn't working:

```
$HOME > file1
```

The op displayed on the screen, not in `file1`.

Comment: It's not just showing the value on screen. It's giving you an error like `bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `echo` to get the output.

```
echo "$HOME" > file1
```

(ie, use double quotes) to avoid variable expansion of $HOME –
dawg

Comment: This breaks if I happen to have `/home/has    spaces` in `$HOME`, or any glob character. You should quote the variable expansion.

Comment: Please do `echo "$HOME" > file1` (ie, use double quotes) to avoid variable expansion of `$HOME`

Comment: Spaces in `$HOME` shouldn't be a problem.  However, glob characters will be.  Isn't it? `x="a b"; echo $x > t; echo "$x" >> tt` and files `t` and `tt` will have same content.